# WordPress: Custom Order By

Tags: wordpress

I have a series of events and I want to list all events but have the most current and future events at the top in order, then have the past events at the bottom using the WP_Query. For example I have these dates and the current date is 2019-12-03.

2019-12-01
2019-12-02
2019-12-03 (current date)
2019-12-04
2019-12-05
2019-12-06
2019-12-07

How I want to order them is

2019-12-03 (current date)
2019-12-04
2019-12-05
2019-12-06
2019-12-07
2019-12-01
2019-12-02

Comment: The date through which you want to sort the event post are stored in "wp_postmeta" table?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a two-tiered `ORDER BY` clause, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    date_col < CURDATE(),
    date_col;
```

The first expression `date_col < CURDATE()` is a boolean expression, which would be true (1) for dates earlier than today at midnight, and false (0) otherwise.  This places all dates in the future before all dates in the past.  Then, we use a second level sort to order all dates ascending.

### Demo

Comment: Thank you, I know that I can do that with a standard MySQL query but trying to do this with the WP_Query for WordPress.  I updated my post to clarify that.